# Use sqldf in R - cannot specify correct username

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

I just downloaded `R` package called `sqldf` just for fun, but have not been able to run it correctly so far. When I try to do some query using `iris` datasets:

```
sqldf("select * from iris limit 5")
```

the error occurred saying `Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'myUserName'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type`

So I opened its help documentation and then run the following query:

```
sqldf("select * from iris limit 5", user="myUser")
```

the error message is the same as the above, which would mean that I failed to specify my `user` argument correctly, given that the error message doesn't change to `Access denied for user 'myUser'@'localhost')`.

So how can I fix it and run it correctly?

For your information when I use `RMySQL`, I use the following arguments in order to make connection.

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"),username="myUser",password="myPass",host="myHost",unix.sock="/tmp/mysql.sock",dbname="myDB")
```

I'm on OS X 10.9.1 and use MySQL 5.6 installed via homebrew, and R version 3.0.2 and sqldf version 0.4-6.

Thanks.

Comment: You get that error if you start a fresh R session, do `require(sqldf)` and that one `sqldf` call? Its got no reason to even think about using your MySQL DB, so why is it? Are yo not telling us the whole story? Have you set any options elsewhere?

Comment: Hmm.... When I quitted my current session and restarted it, then run `library(sqldf)` and run the query, I got the successful result. So maybe it means I cannot use both `sqldf` and `RMySQL` at the same time, right?

Comment: For your information, when I imported `RMySQL` after the successful `sqldf` query, the above issue arose again.

Comment: What does `getOption("sqldf.driver")` say before and after requiring `RMySQL`? I suspect its setting a default for `sqldf` and you aren't specifying your username **and** password in the `sqldf` call.

Comment: (1) If you don't want to use MySQL and instead want to use the default SQLite just make sure the RMySQL R package is not loaded and the `sqldf.driver` is not set (or it is set and set to `"SQLite"`).  (2) If you do want to use MySQL then set up a `my.cnf` file as described in the `Note` section of `?sqldf`.

Comment: Spacedman, `getOption("sqldf.deiver")` returned `NULL` in both circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by making sure that sqldf works with SQLLite.

```
head(sqldf("select * from iris",drv='SQLite'))
```

Next, I would highly recommend that you always use the drv= param or explicitly set the sqldf.driver variable.  Reling on the order of library(..) calls can cause bugs later.

If you are doing something simple, you can use SQLLite because it is fast and has few dependencies (so, for example, if you move your code, you dont have to install MySQL).  If you are using Dates, SQLLite is not great so you might want to use MySQL.
As mentioned in the comments and in the notes at the bottom of ?sqldf, you need to setup a my.cnf for mysql with a [Client] section so that all clients including sqldf use a specific login. Also make sure the dbname is set like so:

```
options(sqldf.driver = "RMySQL")
options(RMySQL.dbname = "rtest")
head(sqldf("select * from iris"))
```

I havent found a reliable way to use MySQL without a my.cnf.  Using an explicit connection for sqldf also doesnt work for me.  I think PostreSQL is better because you can set the username,etc from inside R per the documentation.

Comment: If you do not specify the database via the `"sqldf.driver"` option or in the `drv=` arg then which database is used depends on which database driver packages are loaded but it does not depend on the order of any library calls.  Changing the order of the library calls will have no effect on the result.  See the explanation of the `drv=` argument in the `?sqldf` help file.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the first error because sqldf was using mysql by default in my case. Than, I switched it to SQLite and it worked using the following command.

```
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have loaded RMySQL Package try to detach both RMySQL and sqldf packages and load sqldf package.its works for me. please see my below code

```
detach(package:RMySQL)
detach(package:sqldf)
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from iris limit 5",user="sa", password = "root", host = "192.168.200.182", port=3377)
```